# Getting all Links from a page Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using beautifulsoup to get all the links from a page. My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.acontecaeventos.com.br/marketing-promocional-sao-paulo'
r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

soup.find_all('href')
```

All that I get is:

```
[]
```

How can I get a list of all the href links on that page?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are telling the `find_all` method to find `href` tags, **not** attributes.

You need to find the `<a>` tags, they're used to represent link elements.

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
```

Later you can access their `href` attributes like this:

```
link = links[0]          # get the first link in the entire page
url  = link['href']      # get value of the href attribute
url  = link.get('href')  # or like this
```

Comment: But when I do that, I just get the first link:
http://www.acontecaeventos.com.br/
Should I do a for loop and get them all?

Comment: `links = soup.find_all('a')` gives you a list of all the links. I used the first link as an example in the bottom code in the answer. And yes loop over the `links` list to access all the links found.

Answer (score 14):

Replace your last line:

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
```

By that line :

```
links = [a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

It will scrap all the `a` tags, and for each `a` tags, it will append the `href` attribute to the links list.

If you want to know more about the for loop between the `[]`, read about [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of every`href` regardless of tag use:

```
href_tags = soup.find_all(href=True)   
hrefs = [tag.get('href') for tag in href_tags]
```